# Magnific Popup - gallery images not displaying

Tags: magnific-popup

I'm trying to use Magnific Popup in collaboration with elevateZoom, I have it working to a point where I have bound a click handler to the zoom container, which in this case is the `.product-image-gallery` div.

If I pass a single image src, e.g. `$j('.product-image-gallery .gallery-image').attr('src');` as the `src:` argument then I get a popup with an image, but as soon as I pass a more general selector such as the `.gallery-image` on its own, i get a 'The image could not be loaded' message.

The aim is to have the popup let me cycle through all the avaliable product images.

HTML:

```
<div class="product-image-gallery">
    <img id="image-main" class="gallery-image visible" src="example1.jpg" alt="Title" title="Title" />
    <img id="image-0" class="gallery-image" src="example1.jpg" data-zoom-image="example1.jpg" />
    <img id="image-1" class="gallery-image" src="example2.jpg" data-zoom-image="example2.jpg" />
    <img id="image-2" class="gallery-image" src="example3.jpg" data-zoom-image="example3.jpg" />
</div>
```

JS (`$j` because jQuery is in noConflict mode):

```
    $j.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {
    src: '.gallery-image', 
    type: 'image',
    gallery: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up building an object then passing that to magnific-popup, my solution:

```
$j('.product-image-gallery').bind('click', function(){

        galleryObj = [];
        $j('.product-image-gallery .gallery-image').not('#image-main').each(function() {

            var src = $j(this).data('zoom-image'),
                type = 'image'; // it's always an image :)

            image = {};
            image ["src"] = src;
            image ["type"] = type;

            galleryObj.push(image);
        });

        // open the popup
       $j.magnificPopup.open({
            items: galleryObj,
            gallery: {
                enabled: true
            },
       });
});
```